# Effective image switching on drag motion

Tags: android, image, drag

I have **200 images on sdcard** which represent a **360 view** of an object frame-by-frame.
I want to let the user 'rotate' the object by dragging the finger over the image.

I have no problem with implementing the drag event, the problem is with loading and switching between images. Caching all of the images before displaying the Activity is impossible due to **limited VM memory** (the images are quite big, resolution is over SVGA) for the process. Loading images on drag event is **ineffective** - far from even acceptable.

Has anyone faced such a problem or similar?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limited VM memory that you mention, also called VM heap size, which is about 16Mb, only affects memory allocated in Java. You can allocate more memory in native code. On real devices, there is typically hundreds of megabytes of RAM.

However, if you application uses too much memory it may still get killed by the system. So, when you need to deal with large memory, the best solution is to use memory file mapping, with the Linux mmap() facility. This is rather smart and functions as a swap. Using mmap() you may even map more memory than the actual physical RAM size, and the kernel will load/unload memory pages as needed from the underlying file.

However, I don't think that you can use mmapped memory with standard widgets such as ImageView. Plus, to obtain smooth image switching and scrolling in what you explain, I believe that OpenGL is required.

So I'd recommend to load and decode images into an mmaped memory region in order to use them efficiently as OpenGL textures (there's an [android-ndk thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_frm/thread/6d60f6bcc5cec83a/eeda250dfc781671) with details about this, see [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/msg/b2c638f769c4f07f) and the ones that follow).

Comment: I was afraid of that... so there is no way to get this done in pure Java? The last time I used c++ was a couple of years ago... and I'm also not super-comfortable with OpenGL.  Anyway, thanks a lot for the response

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't see a way to do this in pure Java. Also, it might look ok without hardware graphics acceleration (eg OpenGL) on your device, but I doubt it will be smooth on some others. I mean smooth as in a video, that is: high framerate. The native part could actually be very small I think, just a few routines to deal with the heavy work, and you could code all the rest in Java, calling a few native methods.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to use less photos and/or decrease image resolution.
You could use less images at a lower resolution and then when the image stops rotating, load in the high def photo.
200 photos is a lot just for a 360 degree photo.

Comment: Unfortunately neither using less photos nor decreasing the resolution is an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip some images and deform closest/interpolate 2 closest to serve skipped image.

Once rotation stop, load correct image. This way even slight rotation is noticable (and thereticaly you can rotate with even greater granularity.

But this is more demanding on computing power, so its trade of.

Comment: I'll try it out, but even with this solution I'll have to create miniatures of the images and keep them in memory - not sure how much I'll need to consume.